# Calling Session.close() on HibernateDaoSupport

Tags: hibernate

Hi
I'm using HibernateDaoSupport for my application to do hibernate related actions(Save, update etc).
Well I'm getting the hibernate session by calling `getSession()` to create a criteria.

 After getting my result should I call `session.close();` or will it automatically get released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idiomatic way to use `Session` in `HibernateDaoSupport` is to call `execute()` or `executeFind()` on `HibernateTemplate` obtained from `getHibernateTemplate()`. With this approach you won't need to manage your session manually.

Comment: Thanks I think I could use `executeFind()` for my need